# Function address by ordinal Linux?

Tags: c++, linux

Does Linux have anything to retrieve function address by ordinal or index from a shared object?

I ask because I am writing an OpenGL wrapper and I had to do the following for all 300+ functions:

```
module->AddressOf(funcs[0],"glAccum");
module->AddressOf(funcs[1],"glAlphaFunc");
module->AddressOf(funcs[2],"glAreTexturesResident");
module->AddressOf(funcs[3],"glArrayElement");
module->AddressOf(funcs[4],"glBegin");
module->AddressOf(funcs[5],"glBindTexture");
module->AddressOf(funcs[6],"glBitmap");
module->AddressOf(funcs[7],"glBlendFunc");
module->AddressOf(funcs[8],"glCallList");
module->AddressOf(funcs[9],"glCallLists");
module->AddressOf(funcs[10],"glClear");
module->AddressOf(funcs[11],"glClearAccum");
module->AddressOf(funcs[12],"glClearColor");
module->AddressOf(funcs[13],"glClearDepth");
module->AddressOf(funcs[14],"glClearIndex");
module->AddressOf(funcs[16],"glClearStencil");
module->AddressOf(funcs[17],"glClipPlane");
module->AddressOf(funcs[18],"glColor3b");
module->AddressOf(funcs[19],"glColor3bv");
module->AddressOf(funcs[20],"glColor3d");
```

So on and so forth.. And on windows I can do:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 385; ++i)
   module->AddressOf(funcs[i], (const char*)i);
```

And that's it! The address of each function is stored in `funcs[I]`.
Does Linux have anything similar to the above?

Notes:

`Module->AddressOf` is equivalent to:

```
bool Module::AddressOf(void* &func, const char* name) 
{
    #if defined _WIN32 || defined _WIN64
    func = (void*)GetProcAddress(handle, name);
    #else
    func = dlsym(handle, name);
    #endif

    return func != nullptr;
}
```

And yes I do check for errors by iterating through the func array and seeing if any of them are `NULL`.

Examples of Ordinal values on Windows:

[image]

Comment: You don't explain what `Module->AddressOf` is really doing (i.e. what do you use `GetProcAddress` for in Windows). Do you test against its failure?

Comment: Added an implementation the `AddressOf`. In windows I can load functions by number/index/ordinal OR by name. I'm trying to figure out how to load by number/index/ordinal in Linux and NOT by name.. It's tedious typing 385 function names.

Comment: How does your code (even on Windows) know that index 12 corresponds to `glClearColor` ? What would it do with `func[12]` ?  Please edit your question to explain that.

Comment: glAccum corresponds to index 1 on Windows. It always does. I added a picture showing it. I've tested it on 7 machines each with different drivers and AMD, NVidia and Intel GFX cards. I've tested from XP to 8.1. All the system modules on Windows exports functions by name and their corresponding ordinal value doesn't seem to ever change between OS versions either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Linux, you could use the [dlopen(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/dlopen.3.html) and `dlsym` functions. Don't forget to pass `-rdynamic` when linking your main program.

Of course you need to know the name of a function to get its address with `dlsym`

Notice that you can get symbols inside the main program by `dlopen`-ing it as `NULL`

Be afraid of C++ [name mangling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_mangling). Use `extern "C"` to disable it.

BTW, if you mean

```
 for (int i = 0; i < 385; ++i)
    module->AddressOf(funcs[i], (const char*)i);
```

(I guess you had a typo: your code mixed `I` and `i`) I am surprised it would work reliably even on Windows: when `i` is 50, `(const char*)i`  is `(const char*)50` which is unlikely to be a valid string. On Linux it certainly is not (since the first 4Kpage of the address space is not mapped, and I imagine it is also the case on Windows, which I do not know).

However, [GetProcAddress](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683212%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) is documented as handling

> function's ordinal value. If this parameter is an ordinal value, it must be in the low-order word; the high-order word must be zero.

I don't know what is the ordinal value of a function (in some shared library), and AFAIK Linux does not have such a concept. And even if your code works on Windows, how does it know that `funcs[5]` corresponds to `glBindTexture` ? You need to give that information to your code somewhere!

On Linux if you want to get the name of a function from its address you could use `dladdr`

If you need to get the addresses of OpenGL functions you need to process each of their names!

Perhaps you could collect the many names of OpenGL functions in some array. You could use some scripting (perhaps some `awk` scripts working on some OpenGL headers, or perhaps customizing your [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) compiler with [MELT](http://gcc-melt.org/)) to collect them.

You might perhaps use some ELF reading library like `libelf` and scan the ELF symbol table. You could perhaps `popen` some command like `nm -D libopengl.so`...

Read [Drepper's paper: *How To Write Shared Libraries*](http://people.redhat.com/drepper/dsohowto.pdf); it explains all this in details!

Comment: I'll accept this. It doesn't seem like Ordinals exist on Linux. Guess I have to write a script to get all the names into an array or map.

Comment: @Brandon: You're right, there are no ordinals in Linux. And truth to be told, you should not use them in Windows either. The problem with ordinals is, that the only way to make them work reliably is to write a `.def` file and explicitly specify them for each and every symbol. These days nobody does that anymore, it's all `__dllspec(export)` and any ordinal is just an implicit number. And any new build of a DLL may break it. Oh, and about that paper by Drepper: You should enjoy this with a healthy amount of salt; Drepper has/had a reputation in the Linux community to break things several times.